# No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment' has been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a problem when I want to fire `add-migration` command for a ASP MVC Core 2 project.

> No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment' has been registered.

Here is my **Startup.cs:**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContextPool<SampleArchContext>((serviceProvider, optionsBuilder) =>
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider); // It's added to access services from the dbcontext, remove it if you are using the normal `AddDbContext` and normal constructor dependency injection.
        });

        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.AllowEmptyInputInBodyModelBinding = true;
        }).AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions =>
        {
            jsonOptions.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        });
    }

    public void Configure(
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        IApplicationBuilder app,
        IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
             .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
             .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();

            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
        app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "bower_components")),
            RequestPath = "/bower_components",
            EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false
        });            
    }
}
```

**Program.cs:**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
                config.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath);
                config.AddInMemoryCollection(new[]
                       {
                         new KeyValuePair<string,string>("the-key", "the-value")
                       })
                       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", reloadOnChange: true, optional: false)
                       .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", optional: true)
                       .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.AddDebug();
                logging.AddConsole();
            })
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) =>
            {
                options.ValidateScopes = context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

**context:**

```
public interface IContext
{
    DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
    EntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;
    int SaveChanges();
}
public class SampleArchContext : DbContext, IContext
{
    public SampleArchContext(DbContextOptions<SampleArchContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Country>(build =>
        {
            build.Property(category => category.Name).HasMaxLength(450).IsRequired();
        });
    }
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var modifiedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(x => x.Entity is IAuditableEntity
                && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified));

        foreach (var entry in modifiedEntries)
        {
            IAuditableEntity entity = entry.Entity as IAuditableEntity;
            if (entity != null)
            {
                string identityName = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
                DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

                if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
                {
                    entity.CreatedBy = identityName;
                    entity.CreatedDate = now;
                }
                else
                {
                    base.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
                    base.Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedDate).IsModified = false;
                }
                entity.UpdatedBy = identityName;
                entity.UpdatedDate = now;
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<SampleArchContext>
{    
    public SampleArchContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var service = new ServiceCollection();
        service.AddOptions();
        //service.AddScoped<IHostingEnvironment, CustomHostingEnvironment>();
        service.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, LoggerFactory>();
        var serviceProvider = service.BuildServiceProvider();
        var hostingEnvirement = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHostingEnvironment>();
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
           .SetBasePath(basePath: hostingEnvirement.ContentRootPath)
           //.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .Build();
        service.AddSingleton(provider => configuration);
        serviceProvider = service.BuildServiceProvider();

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SampleArchContext>();
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDbContextConnection");
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        return new SampleArchContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

And here is my `appsetting.json :`

**appsetting.json :**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AppDbContextConnection": "Server=localhost; Database=CoreDbName;Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

I've searched a lot but I couldn't found a solution to this problem, How can I fix it?

Comment: Is the database context in the same project as your ASP MVC Core 2 project?

Comment: No It's in another project.

Comment: Have you chosen the project containing the database context as your "Default project" in the Package Manager Console? If not, the ``Add-Migration`` command gets confused over not being able to find a database context in the project.

Comment: No, Do you mean startup project? How can I do this?

Comment: Assuming that you are using Package Manager console for it, it should be found in the upper part of the view, as seen in this screenshot: http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/UploadFile/22da8c/package-manager-console-in-visual-studio/Images/pm%20test%20module06.jpg

Comment: Oh yes, of course. I set default project to project that contains my context.

Comment: Looking at the implementation of your database context, its quite obvious that a part of your web application "leaked" into it. The problem is this line: `var hostingEnvirement = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHostingEnvironment>();`

As no hosting environment is available, the project can't start, and the database can't configure its migration.

The best solution would be to eliminate any references to any web-related elements in the database context class, and keep the entire data-access project clean of anything but data-access related logic.

Answer (score 3):

There's a new application pattern in ASP.NET Core 2. See [Migrating from ASP.NET Core 1.x to ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/#update-main-method-in-programcs) for details.

EF Core no longer attempts to directly invoke `Startup.ConfigureServices()`. In version 2.0, it will look for a static `Program.BuildWebHost()` method and get your application services from that.

To adopt the new pattern, update your `Program` class to look like this.

```
public class Program
{
    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
                config.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath);
                config.AddInMemoryCollection(new[]
                       {
                         new KeyValuePair<string,string>("the-key", "the-value")
                       })
                       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", reloadOnChange: true, optional: false)
                       .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", optional: true)
                       .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.AddDebug();
                logging.AddConsole();
            })
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) =>
            {
                options.ValidateScopes = context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        return host;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I get this error : `Entity Framework services have not been added to the internal service provider. Either remove the call to UseInternalServiceProvider so that EF will manage its own internal services, or use the method from your database provider to add the required services to the service provider (e.g. AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer).`, But I still get the same error after I removed `optionsBuilder.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider)`  from startup.

Comment: Hmm.. does it work if you switch from `AddDbContextPool` to just `AddDbContext`?