# Autofac assembly scanning - .NET Core

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

I've been trying to get assembly scanning working in my .NET core 2.0 project.

The exception I am getting

```
Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=The requested service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHostOptions' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.
  Source=Autofac
  StackTrace:
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at Track4Corp.VehicleDatabase.Server.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\VehicleDatabase-server\src\Track4Corp.VehicleDatabase.Server\Program.cs:line 10
```

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace Track4Corp.VehicleDatabase.Server
{
  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
  }
}
```

Startup class

```
public class Startup
  {
    public Autofac.IContainer ApplicationContainer { get; private set; }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; private set; }

    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
//TODO: Move out of code before release
      services.AddDbContext<UserDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("Server=DESKTOP-9L9IGFE;Database=DB;Trusted_Connection=True;"));

      //Autofac Assembly Registration
      ApplicationContainer = AutoFacAssemblyRegistration.RegisterAllAssemblies();

      return new AutofacServiceProvider(ApplicationContainer);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }

      app.Run(async (context) =>
      {
       await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
      });
```

So my actually builder i moved to another project, where I for now scan on a hardcorded path where I know all my dll files are located. I ran it in debug mode and see all of them being there.

```
  public class AutoFacAssemblyRegistration
  {
    public static IContainer RegisterAllAssemblies()
    {
      var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
      string executingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
      // string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(executingDirectory, "*.dll");
      string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"PATH_HERE", "*.dll");

      var listOfAssemblies = new List<Assembly>();
      foreach (string item in files)
      {
        listOfAssemblies.Add(item: Assembly.LoadFile(item));
      }
      builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(listOfAssemblies.ToArray()).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
      //builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(listOfAssemblies.ToArray());

      return builder.Build();
    }
  }
```

I also tried different sort of solutions to register the assemblies, such as

```
foreach (Assembly item in listOfAssemblies)
{
  System.Type[] assemblyType = item.GetTypes();
  foreach (System.Type typeItem in assemblyType)
  {
    if (typeItem.IsInterface)
    {
      Autofac.Builder.IRegistrationBuilder<object, Autofac.Builder.ConcreteReflectionActivatorData,
        Autofac.Builder.SingleRegistrationStyle> registration =
        builder.RegisterType(typeItem).AsImplementedInterfaces();

      if (typeItem.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ISingletonDependency))))
      {
        registration.SingleInstance();
      }
      else
      {
        registration.InstancePerRequest();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am wondering if I am doing something wrong, or perhaps this is not possible in .NET core 2.1 projects?

Would be nice if anyone could hint me in the right direction, how to solve my problem.

Comment: Kindly check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46150730/no-service-for-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-hosting-ihostingenvironment-has-been

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue and solved it by adding `containerBuilder.Populate(serviceCollection)` before doing `containerBuilder.Build()`.

Following the sample you provided in your question, it would look something like this -

```
  public class AutoFacAssemblyRegistration
  {
    public static IContainer RegisterAllAssemblies(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
      builder.Populate(services);
      string executingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
      // string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(executingDirectory, "*.dll");
      string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"PATH_HERE", "*.dll");

      var listOfAssemblies = new List<Assembly>();
      foreach (string item in files)
      {
        listOfAssemblies.Add(item: Assembly.LoadFile(item));
      }
      builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(listOfAssemblies.ToArray()).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
      //builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(listOfAssemblies.ToArray());

      return builder.Build();
    }
  }
```