# Autofac automate assembly scanning with Interfaces - .net core 3.0 - Register according to Lifetime

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I realize this question is asked a lot. But I cannot figure out the solution to this problem.

**The thing i am trying to resolve is create three seperate interfaces (Singleton Scoped, InstancePerRequest).
And register all the services under their implemented interface, without having to manually add them to DI container.**

[Autofac Scanning Assemblies for certain class type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159277/autofac-scanning-assemblies-for-certain-class-type)

[Autofac register assembly types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838880/autofac-register-assembly-types)

[Autofac assembly scanning - .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568917/autofac-assembly-scanning-net-core)

**Before you say duplicate hear me out.**

> I have provided a solution to the question asked. But i would like to search the whole solution and not be restricted to a project. I have addded my autofac module inside the Services project so it registers what exists inside services projects. Please see **answer** below for a better understanding.
>
> I have tried to implement a multi project scanning see code below. It does not work.

Here is my Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

Here is my Configure container in my Startup Class. I have left out all others since this is just a new ASP.NET Core Project.

```
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        //builder.RegisterType<EpisodeServices>().As<IEpisodeService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope(); This works

        var executingDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        //The sth is my Solution's header for example Sth.Core, Sth.Models, Sth.Services all are childs to the Sth Solution
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(executingDirectory, "Sth.*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        var listOfAssemblies = new List<Assembly>();
        foreach (var file in files)
            listOfAssemblies.Add(Assembly.LoadFile(file));

        builder
            .RegisterAssemblyTypes(listOfAssemblies.ToArray())
            .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ISthScopedService))))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
```

So far so good.

Here is an example Service so you can fully see my implementation.

```
public class EpisodeServices : IEpisodeService
{
    public IList<Episode> GetEpisodes()
    {
        return new List<Episode>
        {
            new Episode { Id = 1, Name = "Some Name", Description = "Some Description" }
        };
    }
}
```

And here is the interface:

```
public interface IEpisodeService : ISthScopedService
{
    IList<Episode> GetEpisodes();

}
```

Here is the injection to the controller

```
public class EpisodeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IEpisodeService _episodeService;

    public EpisodeController(IEpisodeService episodeService)
    {
        _episodeService = episodeService;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var data = _episodeService.GetEpisodes();
        return Content(data[0].Name);
    }
}
```

If i run this like this i get an `Invalid Operation Exception: Unable to resolve service for type namespace.IEpisodeService` while attempting to activate `EpisodeController`.

Could someone provide more implementation details on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution provided does not resolve solution scanning. But it uses assembly scanning. You may as well view this as a step-by-step guide on how to achieve this. Our Solution Looks sth like this.

```
Sth.Core --> Class Library.

Sth.Services --> Class Library(Assembly scanning will happen here).

Sth.Web --> ASP.NET Core MVC project.

The Sth.Core has our three-lifetime interfaces which our Services need to inherit from.
 - ISthInstanceService
 - ISthScopedService
 - ISthSingletonService
```

**Sth.Web.Program.cs**

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory()) //Add this
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

**Sth.Web,Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterModule(new SthModule()); // This is the autofac Module. We add it later at the Services Project
        }
```

Now for our Services Project.Here we need to create our autofac module. The one asp.net app instantiated.

```
public class SthModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        
        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        builder
            .RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
            .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ISthScopedService))))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope(); // Add similar for the other two lifetimes
        base.Load(builder);
    }
}
```

The above code will scan all the Services project and add all the classes that inherit from the ISthScopedService and register them to the container.

Sth.Service.EpisodeService.cs

```
 public class EpisodeServices : IEpisodeService
{
    public IList<Episode> GetEpisodes()
    {
        return new List<Episode>
        {
            new Episode { Id = 1, Name = "Imposter Syndrome", Description = "Imposter syndrome" }
        };
    }
}
```

And the interface.

```
public interface IEpisodeService : ISthCommonService
    {
        IList<Episode> GetEpisodes();
    }
```

Now we have implemented assembly scanning(auto-registration) for our services project.