# Auto resolve DI with Scrutor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, scrutor

I have app service `ExperienceAppService` that implements interface `IExperienceAppService`.

I try to use Scrutoк for auto registering

I have this code in Startup file

```
 services.Scan(scan =>
            scan.FromCallingAssembly()
                .AddClasses()
                .AsMatchingInterface());
```

It supposed to register interface . But I got this error

> Unable to resolve service for type 'TooSeeWeb.Core.Interfaces.Experiences.IExperienceAppService' while attempting to activate 'TooSeeWeb.Controllers.ExperienceController'.

Where is my trouble?

Comment: The issue i think is that your Interfaces and registered classes are in different assemblies try adding them on the same project. Then everything should work. Also make sure that the Scanner from Scrutor is in the same project as well. I have tried sth similar here with Autofac -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59164555/autofac-automate-assembly-scanning-net-core-3-0-register-according-to-lifetim/59236011#59236011. I never managed to do Solution Scanning.

Comment: Yeah, that helps@panoskarajohn