# Autofac assembly scanning with interfaces

Tags: c#, autofac, ioc-container, asp.net-core-7.0, autofac-module

Project is built with .NET 7 MVC.

I have created 3 interfaces in my "Application" class library. I will implement these interfaces on my other interfaces or classes.

I want the dependencies to be automatically resolve by scanning the assembly, like if the interface or class is implementing "ITransientLifetime" then it should resolve as "InstancePerDependency". If any class or interface has "ISingletonLifetime" then it should resolve as Singleton Lifetime.

Below is my project architecture. 
[Project Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mBGh.png)

Here is my code from Application class library. 
**ISingletonLifetime.cs**

```
public interface ISingletonLifetime 
{
}
```

**ITransientLifetime.cs**

```
public interface ITransientLifetime
{
}
```

**IEmailSender.cs**

```
public interface IEmailSender : ISingletonLifetime
{
   void SendEmail(string email);
}
```

**EmailSender.cs**

```
public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    public void SendEmail(string email)
    {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And here is the code from "Mvcapp" 
**AutofacIocContainer.cs**

```
public class AutofacIocContainer : Module
{
    private readonly Type singletonInterface = typeof(ISingletonLifetime);
    private readonly Type transientInterface = typeof(ITransientLifetime);
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        builder
         .RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
         .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsAssignableFrom(transientInterface)))
         .AsImplementedInterfaces()
         .InstancePerDependency();

          base.Load(builder);
     }   
 }
```

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());
builder.Host.ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(containerBuilder =>
{
      containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new AutofacIocContainer());
})
```

Can anybody guide me on this. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59164555/autofac-automate-assembly-scanning-with-interfaces-net-core-3-0-register-ac) is the same what I am looking for but I am unable to resolve my dependency IEmailSender. I am getting below error:

**InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Application.Interfaces.IEmailSender' while attempting to activate 'MvcAppCore.Controllers.HomeController'.**

Also I am thinking on how to handle the scenario like below:

```
public class Test : ISingletonLifetime, ITransientLifetime
{
}
```

Thank You

Comment: Why does the `IEmailSender` interface include the `ISingletonLifetime` interface? Dependency lifetime is (at best) an implementation concern, so it seems as though implementation details are leaking through to the abstraction.

Comment: Also, please edit the post so that the image is in the post, instead of a link someone has to click on. If you want people to help you, you should make it as easy for them to do that as possible.

Comment: "Why does the IEmailSender interface include the ISingletonLifetime interface?". I am just giving the example.

Comment: To help you in the future, consider that the question title currently does not actually tell us anything about what you're trying to do - it's very vague. I'm glad you got help this time, but I know I usually skip over questions that don't have a good, descriptive title because it usually indicates someone has not thought through what the actual question is.

Comment: Hey @TravisIllig I am new to the community, I am learning but will definitely try to improve my question in the coming time. Thank You

Comment: [Here's a great article that might help.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Take care!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You marked your `IEmailSender` as `ISingletonLifetime`
- You are registering only implementations of `ITransientLifetime`
- Hence you cannot resolve `IEmailSender` because it is not registered.

A valid way to handle

```
public class Test : ISingletonLifetime, ITransientLifetime
{
}
```

Is by throwing an exception at composition time. But then, I do not know your requirements in handling this.

Comment: Oh God. :) :) That's a good catch. I registered only the ITransientLifetime and that is why it was failing. Thank your very much for your answer. And regarding the 2nd scenario I would like to throw exception when more than one lifetime implemented on a class or interface. How can I do that?

Comment: Add an additional query on your `assemblies` variable and check if there is any type that is concrete and has multiple of your interfaces implemented. If you find any of those just throw an exception to your liking.